# C# Class Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, reflection, dependency-injection

i need to do something like this in c#. But in the Exec(object) i got a compilation error.

```
public class ParentClass { }
public class class1 : ParentClass
{
}
public class class2 : ParentClass
{
}
public class class3 : ParentClass
{
}

public class MasterClass 
{
    public void ExecutionMethod(ParentClass myObject)
    {
        //some code
        Exec(myObject);
        //some code
    }

    public void Exec(class1 obj)
    {
        //some code
    }
    public void Exec(class2 obj)
    {
        //some code
    }
    public void Exec(class3 obj)
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

I solved using Reflection but i think must be a better approach, somebody could give me a nice idea

Comment: What compilation error did you get?

Comment: @EJoshuaS he is passing in a `ParentClass`  but he has not overload that takes a `ParentClass` in.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes, I did see that, just thought it was worth asking for the post to include the full error text (otherwise it's a lot less useful to future readers)

Comment: Have you heard of a command pattern? The classes you had Class1, Class2, Class3 will be concrete commands and MasterClass will be Invoker ( CommandManager), You can keep a list (Dictionary) each command and then the commandManager will have a logic to execute the right command

Comment: Yes, in this case i need to overload to takes a ParentClass. but i do not need that.
I need a master method that could take any class that inherit from parentClass, and after pass the object to an specific method for an special behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ScottChamberlain pointed out in the comments, you don't have any methods that take an argument of type `ParentClass`.

Take a look at the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) - if you've done your implementation properly, you can substitute an instance of, for example, `class1` for an instance of `ParentClass`, but the converse is *not* true at all.

Odds are, you don't need (or want) the overloads anyway. Just have `ParentClass` be an abstract class with an abstract `Execute` method that all child classes have to implement, then you can just call `Execute` on the class directly without bothering with the overloads. Even better, just make `ParentClass` an interface. (This is sometimes called the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) by the way).

```
public interface IParent {
  void Execute();
}

public class class1 : ParentClass {
   //Execute method implementation
}

public class class2 : ParentClass {
   // ...
}

public class class3 : ParentClass {
  // ....
}

public class MasterClass 
{
    public void ExecutionMethod(IParent myObject)
    {
        //some code
        myObject.Execute();
        //some code
    }
}
```

Comment: If I may, you might want to replace `ParentClass` with `IParent` in the declarations of `class1`, `class2` and `class3`. Of course, I'm certain the OP has already figured that on their own...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you have a look at object-oriented design patterns. Specifically, the strategy pattern for this problem. Anyway, you can implement what you want like this:

```
public interface IParent 
{ 
    void Exec(); 
}
public class Child1 : IParent
{
    void Exec() { /*code*/ }
}
public class Child2 : IParent
{
    void Exec() { /*code*/ }
}
public class Child3 : IParent
{
    void Exec() { /*code*/ }
}

public class MasterClass 
{
    public void ExecutionMethod(IParent myObject)
    {
        //some code
        myObject.Exec();
        //some code
    }
}
```

You could also use an abstract class instead of an interface, if you wanted the parent class to have some functionality for the Exec method - then the child classes would have to override the method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an interface here

Try changing `ParentClass` like this:

```
public interface IParentClass{}
```

Then make each of your classes implement it, like this:

```
public class class1 : IParentClass
{
}

public class class2 : IParentClass
{
}
```

Then in your MasterClass, try this:

```
public void ExecutionMethod(IParentClass myObject)
{
    //some code
    Exec(myObject);
    //some code
}

public void Exec(IParentClass obj)
{
    //some code
}
```

And then you can pass in any of your classes that implement the `IParentClass`interface.

Now as an enhancement - if you want every implementation of `IParentClass` to have some methods and properties that you can invoke in your Exec method, do it like so:

```
public interface IParentClass
{
    void DoTheThing();
}
```

This will force you to have this method in derived classes, so for example, class1 would look like this:

```
public class class1 : IParentClass
{
    public void DoTheThing() 
    {
        // things get done...
    }
}
public class class2 : IParentClass
{
    public void DoTheThing() 
    {
        // things get done a different way...
    }
}
```

And now in your Exec method, you can invoke like so:

```
public void Exec(IParentClass obj)
{
    obj.DoTheThing();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need a specific behavior depending on the class. For example. If class1 then DoMethod1(class1.Name), if class2 then DoMethod2(class2.PhoneNumber);

That is why i need a specific method foreach class

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how you can define methods for your derived classes.  HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can use command pattern, with dependency injection. I kind of give you an idea below. The concrete implementation will call execute on your receiver ( you logic goes there

```
public interface ICommand
{
    void Execute();
}

public class Command1 : ICommand
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public class Command2 : ICommand
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public class Command3 : ICommand
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class CommandManager
{
    //you should use DI here to inject each concerete implementation of the command
    private Dictionary<string, ICommand> _commands;

    public CommandManager()
    {
        _commands = new Dictionary<string, ICommand>();
    }

    public void Execute(string key)
    {
        _commands[key].Execute();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error your seeing is a result of your class1,2,3 objects being cast as their parent type because of the signature of the ExecutionMethod(xxx). 
And not having an overridden method of Exec that takes a type of 'ParentClass' as the argument.

Probably the simplest method is to create an interface:

```
IDomainObject{}.
public class ParentClass : IDomainObject { }
public void ExecutionMethod(IDomainObject myObject)
    {        
        Exec(myObject);      
    }
```

Using the interface in this way will prevent the downcast during the method call.